# Stuck with Windows 8 on macbook pro

Tags: windows-7, macos, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I use Windows 7 and Mac OSX on macbook pro using bootcamp, few hours back I installed the windows 8 as well without using rEFIt or any other tools.

Now the problem is I always see Mac OSX and Windows as boot option.

When I choose windows 7, the laptop boots into win8. I even tried to change the start up disk from "Start up but still the win8 was loaded.

How do I load the Windows 7 back?

Here's the screen shot of startup disks I have.[image]

`Untitled Windows` is Win8, `Bootcamp windows` is Windows 7

Comment: You need to change the Windows 8 boot process to include the older Windows 7. It won't be doable from OS X.

Comment: @Randolph Thanks, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know, because I've not installed Windows 8 anywhere. I'm sure you'll find something if you search for it.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8:

- Open your desktop,
- Open a Explorer window,
- Find the Control Panel in the address bar,
- System & Security -> Sytem,
- Click Advanced System Settings in the sidebar,
- (Shortcut: open the startmenu and type Advanced system settings, then click the Settings tile)
- In this dialog find the Advanced tab,
- Click the Settings button in the Startup and Recovery part,
- Here you can change your default os or you can set a timer so you can choose which version of Windows you want to start.

In the future don't install a developer preview if you don't intend to use it.